# Can i call a wcf service without knowing the port and not using discovery?

Tags: wcf

Can i call a wcf service without knowing the port and not using discovery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the address uses default port for protocol you don't need to pass it to the URL. For example 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS. But in that case you "know" the port because you don't specify it.

Otherwise no. You always need to know the address and a port is part of it. If you don't know the address you need some discovery to get it.

It is the same as with mail. If you don't know destination address you cannot send a letter.